# SwiftUI Button Tap off Target

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, scrollview, hstack

I have a scroll view of some buttons but for some reason the tap target is below the actual button. The background of the button shows a square behind the circular button. Why can't I select the button where the content is?

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let buttons = ["", ""]
    
    @State var selected: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(buttons, id: \.self) { item in
                    Button {
                        UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                        selected.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text(item)
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .background(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                    .stroke(.black, lineWidth: selected ? 1 : 0)
                            
                            )
                    }
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .contentShape(Circle())
                    .background(.red)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: 40)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate your problem, when clicking any of the two buttons (inside them) both buttons show as they are being clicked at the same time.

I have version 14.1 of XCode and 16.1 of iOS, maybe a different version may cause this problem?

But first you should change the id of the buttons. You are using the same id for both buttons and that is not recommended in a ForEach and could cause problems.